# Write downloaded image to pdfkit using nodejs

Tags: node.js, request, web-scraping, fs, node-pdfkit

I am trying to write an image scraped&downloaded from a website using request to pdfkit.

```js
var request = require('request'),
    PDFDocument = require('pdfkit'),
 doc = new PDFDocument,
 fs = require('fs');

var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('images/0.jpeg')
var r = request(IMAGEURL).pipe(wstream);
r.on('close', function() {
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf/output.pdf'));     
doc.image('images/0.jpeg');
    });
doc.end();
```

Problem is, no image is added to the pdf:-(

This is the error message I get:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: stream.push() after EOF
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Move the `doc.end()` call so that it's inside the function that handles the 'close' event.

```
r.on('close', function() {
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf/output.pdf'));     
  doc.image('images/0.jpeg');
  doc.end();   // <----- *put this here*
});
```

Otherwise you are closing your doc before anything has a chance to write to it, because the request call (and subsequent piping) is all happening asynchronously.